# jQuery Ajax call No element found issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a javascript error on firefox 3.5, when trying to call an ajax method.

Please find the error below:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{1a2c8133-f48f-4707-90f3-1a2b2f2d62e2} Line Number 1, Column 1:

^
```

this is my javascript function:

```
function Update(Id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ROOT_URL + "/sevice/udates.svc/Update?Id=" + Id,
        success: function(response) {

        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you know if your service is being called?  Maybe it's an issue with the value being returned.  Please let us know where you're seeing the error -- in the success handler, in the ajax call itself, etc.

Comment: Have you looked in firebug? It looks like you're getting a completely empty response from the server.

Comment: I'm thinking your question is going to need more specifics, it looks like there may be a problem in your response from your service call.  First return the exact same XML document every time (doesn't depend on "id") and see if that works, try and narrow down the problem a bit, and then edit your post.

Comment: yeah i my method is void. is that the issue? if in case my method id void how can call it in ajax call. Is it mandatory that we need to have some response back from the server after calling the method?

Comment: The core of this problem is that the server-side is returning no content. Firefox seems to require at least some content (e.g. a space) for 2xx status codes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ajax call expects XML back (*perhaps due to bad guessing*) and tries to parse it and fails if nothing is returned or it is not valid XML..

Use the `dataType` option to specify the format of the response.

---

From the comments it looks like some browsers cannot handle an no-content response. So, a workaround for such cases might be to return something from your service (*even a single space*).

Comment: so u mean to say that i need to some thing like what Teja told?

Comment: @Nimesh, yep .. but it depends on what you expect to receive back from the service.. is it XML ? or is it JSON ? HTML ? Text ?

Comment: JSON is the format. I am using an attribute decorated on the WCF service method as WebMessageFormat.Json

Comment: @Nimesh, your should add `dataType: 'json'` then in your options to the ajax call.. You should also use firebug to check the response from the server and see if it returns what you expect it ..

Comment: Gaby, Actually my method return's null from the webservice, it is a void method. So if i give datatype : json, will I able to solve the issue?

Comment: @Nimesh, if you do not expect to get something back from the server. perhaps you should use the `dataType:'text'`. It should not try to do something with a text response...

Comment: Just returning a *something* e.g. a space seems to work fine.

Comment: Returning an empty string, i.e: `context.Response.Write(String.empty)` in aspx.net solved it me

Comment: I've tried dataType text and json and neither one fixed this issue.

Comment: @GrahamLea have you tried the suggestions in the last two comments ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes, I eventually just returned a space and that worked. The dataType seemes to be irrelevant, yet it is the accepted answer. Maybe you could add that part of the solution into your answer?

Answer (score 25):

I fixed the problem by setting mimeType to "text/html"

Comment: Same here. Adding mimeType: 'text/html' to the ajax POST call solved the problem in IceWeasel.

Comment: AWS S3 PUT request returns 200 status code and no ContentType, so jQuery throws this error. Adding `dataType: 'text'` will not help, but also adding `mimeType: 'text/html'` will help.

Comment: @Justinas comment is the only one works for me (Firefox)

Comment: Nice one - fixed for me. I wouldn't have got to this by myself.

Answer (score 10):

I've come across an alternative cause of this - might help someone.

If you make a `$.ajax` request (in my case a `PUT` request) that returns a 200 header but no body content I've seen this same XML Parsing error message occur - even when the `dataType` is set to `json`.

(At least) two solutions work:

- Make all API  `PUT` requests return some content, or
- Return a 204 'No Content' header instead (what I ended up doing)

Comment: I'm already returning a 204 for a DELETE with no response body and I'm still seeing this. :(

Comment: I guess this is a problem with PATCH request I am using. Older versions of the browsers do not support it.

Answer (score 5):

It's a known FireFox bug.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547718
to quick fix this , you maybe can return an response with html structure(but no content).

Comment: I am returning html and have my jQuery ajax set to have dataType: "html", and I also receive this error in Firefox. A bug must have been introduced at some point because I didn't have the error before.

Comment: That seems a right answer, using Mozilla Firefox 46, it is not able to parse PATCH requests.

Answer (score 0):

`async` is also part of options. Also specify the `dataType` as `xml`

```
function Update(Id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "XML",
        url: ROOT_URL + "/sevice/udates.svc/Update?Id=" + Id,
        success: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send html document to the output (the output udates.svc in your case) . If you use ASP.NET, you could do the following:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write("<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>");
Response.Write("<head><title></title></head>");
Response.Write("<body>");
Response.Write("your output");
Response.Write("</body>");
Response.Write("</html>");
Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
Response.End();
```