# XMLHttpRequest blocked on one page but not another?

Tags: javascript

I have two pages, both on the same domain. Both are attempting to get an events feed from Google Calendar. One is successful, one is not. The only difference is that one use jQuery's document.ready, and the other uses window.onload.

Page that works: http://wwwtest.english.wisc.edu/calendar.htm

Page that doesn't work: http://wwwtest.english.wisc.edu/844.htm

The second page is being generated by a CMS, so I don't have as much control over the script's loading order, thus I'm using window.onload to ensure the other scripts are loaded first.

****Additional clarifications below****

Yes, I've done debugging, here is the exact error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/rhrab82ir5qgut1ddv7qj087c8%40group.ca…ar.google.com/public/basic?start=1356847200&end=1360476000&_=1358694509517.
>   Origin http://wwwtest.english.wisc.edu is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

But the confusing part for me is this:

I copied the code from the page that works and only changed two things:

1) I changed from using jQuery's document.ready to using window.onload

2) I changed the jQuery selector

Comment: Not successful in what way?  Are the feeds just not loading?  Are you getting an error?  Have you done any basic debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found your issue with a quick debug in firebug.  Your call

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/rhrab82ir5qgut1ddv7qj087c8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?start=1356850800&end=1360479600&_=1358632991615 
is returning:
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{627004d0-0e97-ca46-9ae8-767df4ae9d4f} Line Number 1, Column 1:

There is some interesting info located at [Cross-domain Ajax call gets no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053995/cross-domain-ajax-call-gets-no-element-found-location-moz-nullprincipal)  and

[jQuery Ajax call No element found issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334969/jquery-ajax-call-no-element-found-issue)

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/rhrab82ir5qgut1ddv7qj087c8%40group.ca…ar.google.com/public/basic?start=1356814800&end=1360443600&_=1358633133560. Origin http://wwwtest.english.wisc.edu is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I use Chrome for debugging such things. Ctrl+Shift+J for JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently full calendar has a specific additional script that is needed to use Google calendar events.

Info here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/

The first example has this script loaded, but the second did not. After adding it the events load properly.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is using a jsonp api, while the second is using an xml api therefore to same origin policy applies, If you can change the second request to use the jsonp api.