# How do I setup my Ajax POST request to prevent "no element found" on empty response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a piece of JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
         url: theRightUrl,
         data: whatToPost,
         logFunction: whatever,
         suppressSuccessLogging: !0
       });
```

and once this code runs the POST goes just fine and the server returns `202 Accepted` and content length set to zero and no content type header. This makes Firefox to show `no element found` error in its JavaScript console.

Looks like the problem is that [Firefox tries to decode the response as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/976200/57428) and the resolution would be to configure the server to return "text/plain" as content type. However I cannot change the server behavior, I have to work it around on the client.

I tried to add `dataType: 'html'` or `dataType: 'text'` which should instruct jQuery to not try parse the response as XML but I see no changes in behavior.

Is there anything I could do to the client side code so that the empty response isn't parsed?

Comment: Couldn't you set an explicit return type on the ajax call using `dataType: 'html'`. I think this error/issue occurs when the ajax call results in no response body from the server. "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @LatheesanKanes: Why not just use `'text'` then?

Comment: Could do. But my idea was that, if you specify an explicit return type using `dataType: 'xxx'`, that error will go away. Untested though...

Comment: @LatheesanKanes: Tested both - and the error message is there anyway.

Comment: Is a request broker viable option? e.g. you make the request to script called `broker.php?rightUrl=xxyyzz` and that in turns calls `rightUrl` and always echos a dummy response like `OK`?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes: Nope, that's too much, it must be a script running on the client without anything like brokers. I wonder why specifying `dataType` has no effect though.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I leave it for someone may need it in the future.

I had the same issue. I was expecting empty response for `done (success)` and JSON for `fail (error)`, I set the dataType: 'json' and it was giving me `no element found` + `JSON.parse` error on `done`. I have sent an empty object `{}` in my response when the request succeeded and set the header to 'application/json', and it solved my problem. Now, response has some value and it is json format. :)

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write("{}");
```

Also, as [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335012/1189105), some browsers complain if the message is completely empty. So, we need to send something with respect to our expected `dataType`, so that no error rises neither from browsers nor from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem only for endpoints that return ResponseEntity with only the HTTPStatus

i have fixed them, setting in JQuery requests:

```
dataType: 'text'
```

and the Controller has to return a Text in the ResponseEntity object:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Process Completed Successfully", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
```