# getJSON parser cannot process JSON output from PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I have a php script which returns the following json from my SQL Server :

```
<?php

$server = "DEVTEST-PC\\SRVCLT";
$options = array("UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"1234","Database"=>"Test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);


if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
//echo "Successfully connected!";


$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT Currency, USDRate FROM Pax.CurrencyRate
WHERE GBPRate BETWEEN 80 AND 800;");

if($result === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

     $myArray['paxcurjson'][] = $row;
}
     echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

Output is as follows :

```
{"paxcurjson":[
{"Currency":"AFN","USDRate":49.5},
{"Currency":"ALL","USDRate":103.567},
{"Currency":"BDT","USDRate":77.562},
{"Currency":"DZD","USDRate":79.6146}]}
```

I am using Jquery to parse it but for some reason it is failing to parse. My code is as follows :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript" >

     var url = 'CurrencyQuery.php';

       $.getJSON(url, function(data){

          for (i = 0; i < data.paxcurjson.length; i++) {

              console.log(data.paxcurjson[2].Currency);

          };

        });

</script>
```

The only error message I'm getting from my console is :

08:52:52.661 no element found1 CurrencyQuery.php:24:4

This basically refers to my PHP script returning the json. I don't have any ideas why this isn't working. I have validated the JSON with an online validator and it seems ok and the Jquery, it should be ok. Could anyone give me a clue ?

Comment: did you tried consoling `data`? use `console.log(data)` and see whats coming. If its JSON object thats coming then you need to use `data = $.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: you display a json data in "CurrencyQuery.php" file ?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your fast response.Tried that, but unfortunately I still end up with the no element found error. I'm pretty sure that getJSON is failing somehow. Maybe there is something wrong with the JSON but I can't quite figure out what it is.

Comment: It is the whole JSON file? Because it looks like it is actually much bigger.

Comment: Nopes, CurrencyQuery.php is a script that goes in my SQL database, runs a query, and outputs it as JSON. A sample of the output is mentionned above in my code.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes it is the whole JSON file. Do you think something is missing ?

Comment: @AshwinJugurnauth It looks like the problem is somewhere in your PHP file. Can you show your PHP file?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev No problems. I will edit my post to include the php file.

Comment: try this first, remove the for loop, then do a console.log of the data. just the response. what do you get?

Comment: @astroanu I tried this earlier. Unfortunately it still gives me the no element found error.

Comment: Quick update. I tried to declare a json object having the same structure as my json output from the php file. I then used parseJSON on it to see if it works. I expected it to fail. At least this way I would know that my JSON file was not in a good format. Unfortunately, it worked just fine :/

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334969/jquery-ajax-call-no-element-found-issue

Comment: @astroanu Does not apply to my case unfortunately. I have isolated the issue. Turns out that if I use getJSON on a .json file in the same folder, I'm able to access it and parse it. Note that .json file is just the output of the php script. It's only when I'm actively calling the php script through getJSON that it just fails. I think it might be some cross-domain issue even if I'm not familiar at all with this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I figured out the solution. I had to wrap the JSON encoded data from my php script in a callback function. I could retrieve the data then. I'm not sure whether this is the best way to deal with this issue but so far it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to change few thing in PHP output to get it handled by Javascript or JQuery

```
<?php
//just set a header before output
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

this always works for me.

one more thing, when you need to use PHP output as JSON API to be parsed in JQuery etc...I suggest you set error handling to false, because errors displayed by PHP can cause json output not readable by jquery

Comment: that is because of same domain policy of the browser